# fatal: remote <Repository> already exists

Tags: bash, git, macos, bitbucket, command-line-interface

As part of the development of a CI & CD flow for the company I work at, I am building a command line program (Bash script on OSX) that

- creates a new local Git repo
- adds some default branches to this repo
- Then adds a new repo to Bitbucket using the next code:

`gitUserName = Joris <-- provided by the user, this is an example
projectName = TestProject <-- provided by the user, this is an example
git remote add $projectName "https://bitbucket.org/$gitUserName/$projectName.git"`

After running this command, I don't see the repository on my Bitbucket account on the website. When I try to re-run this command, it says the repository already exists.

Also, when I run `git push $projectName master` it says `fatal: repository 'https://bitbucket.org/Joris/TestProject.git/' not found`

This behavior seems inconsistent, and I have followed the [Atlassian guide](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository?_ga=2.236395783.765683468.1542616972-1219948015.1542275631) to set this up so I don't really understand why it doesn't add the repository as expected. I do realize that I can also just go on the BitBucket website and add the repository manually, but the purpose of my program is that it generates a fully set-up repository for a user based on as little commands as possible.

Comment: can you change the last command in the script to say `echo git remote add $projectName "https://bitbucket.com/$gitUserName/$projectName.git"` and see what happens?

Comment: Hi! I tried and this is what it says: git remote add TestProject https://bitbucket.com/Joris/TestProject.git
fatal: 'TestProject' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists. This also seems surprising because when I the project I generated in Xcode (it's an iOS project I'm generating in git), it shows all the branches I added to the git.

Comment: looks like one says .com and one says .org

Comment: Sorry that is just a silly reproduction error, corrected it in my question. it should be .org

Comment: I just noticed that running git remote -v also returns an empty respone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `git remote add` documentation says that the command adds a remote to the local repo.  This terminology is, IMO, a bit off; it would better to say it adds a remote *configuration* to the local repository (i.e. configures the repo to *access* a remote).  This does not actually create the remote repo; that must be done separately.

In the case of bitbucket, the "normal" thing to do is to go to the website and create the repo through their UI.  Because you're trying to automate things, you don't want to do that; so in that case, you would need to use the BitBucket REST API, which is documented here: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/reference/rest-api/

The "Core API" section talks about repositories and permissions, so you should be able to script out requests to (if necessary) check if the repo exists and set it up if it doesn't.  You'll just need a way for your script to send HTTP requests and receive the responses.

Answer (score 0):

In your machine:

Create repo:

```
git init
```

Add branches:

```
git checkout -b branchX
git checkout -b branchY
git checkout -b branchZ
```

In Bitbucket website:

Create new repository named TestProject, allow write permissions to user Joris in settings and save. Finally copy the url of the repository, this must be something like bitbucket.mydomain:port/nameofproject/testproject.git (**Notice this is all in lowcase**)

In your machine:

```
git remote add origin theURL
git push origin *:* 
git push origin --tags
```

The last is the command to push all your local repo, this will overwrite the history and tags in your remote repo, but since is a new repo it doesn't matter.

Comment: Hi Johan, Thanks for your quick response. I should add that I am developing a command line program for Continuous Integration & Continuous Deliver Xcode Projects. This means that the purpose of what I'm doing is to let a user run one command in the CLI, and that my program then sets up everything for them, including a remote bitbucket git repo. They shouldn't have to go to the website to do anything by hand. Can this be done?

Comment: You need to use the rest api from attlasian  directly, Maybe you can find useful [https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Git-questions/Programmatically-create-Stash-GIT-repos/qaq-p/204848] (https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Git-questions/Programmatically-create-Stash-GIT-repos/qaq-p/204848 ) and [https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/reference/rest-api/] (https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/reference/rest-api/)